# Angular firestore - getting all data from the same property field after querying an array in a collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all SubjectName of all documents.

[image]

I guess it would look something like this:

```js
  getSubjectForUsertest() {
  return this.db.collection('subjects', ref => ref.where('userId', 'array-contains', 'P8lhYVtJ6rU2jf5UtTxYr04naX83'))
   .get().subscribe(snap => {
     snap.forEach(doc => {
       // Something 
     })
   });
  }
```

Or maybe it's not even possible?